# What would need to happen to push NYC or other urban centers towards holistic sustainability?

Tags: city-living

Structurally or otherwise, is there a way to transition an unsustainable city into a sustainable one? What would needs to occur and what would the effect be? Can modern civilization become sustainable?

Comment: Many thousands of people have been working on this question for many decades, without any definite resolution. Do you perhaps have a much much smaller, more answerable question you'd like to start with instead?

Comment: The first thing to do is to decrease energy consumption. This mean we have to have less *material* expectations. Good luck.